# dplyr pipes - How to change the original dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

When I don't use a pipe, I can change the original daframe using this command

```
df<-slice(df,-c(1:3))%>% # delete top 3 rows
df<-select(df,-c(Col1,Col50,Col51)) # delete specific columns
```

How would one do this with a pipe? I tried this but the `slice` and `select` functions don't change the original dataframe.

```
df%>%
  slice(-c(1:3))%>% 
  select(-c(Col1,Col50,Col51))
```

I'd like to change the original df.

Comment: Then do `df <- df%>%  slice(-c(1:3))%>%   select(-c(Col1,Col50,Col51))`

Comment: or put the assignment at the end if you like: `df %>% ... -> df`

Comment: Or `library(magrittr); df %<>% slice(-(1:3)) %>% select(-c(Col1,Col50,Col51))`.  We can reassign the original data frame with `%<>%`.  Here `df` will be changed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can definitely do the assignment by using an idiom such as `df <- df %>% ...` or `df %>% ... -> df`. But you could also avoid redundancy (i.e., stating `df` twice) by using the `magrittr` compound assignment operator `%<>%` at the beginning of the pipe.

From the `magrittr` vignette:

> The compound assignment pipe operator `%<>%` can be used as the first pipe in a chain. The effect will be that the result of the pipeline is assigned to the left-hand side object, rather than returning the result as usual.

So with your code, we can do

```
library(magrittr)  ## came with your dplyr install
df %<>% slice(-(1:3)) %>% select(-c(Col1, Col50, Col51))
```

This pipes `df` into the expression and updates `df` as the result.

**Update:**  In the comments you note an issue setting the column names.  Fortunately `magrittr` has provided functions for setting attributes in a pipe.  Try the following.

```
df %<>% 
    set_colnames(sprintf("Col%d", 1:ncol(.))) %>% 
    slice(-(1:3)) %>%
    select(-c(Col1,Col50,Col51))
```

Note that since we have a data frame, we can also use `setNames()` (stats) or `set_names()` (magrittr) in place of `set_colnames()`.

---

Thanks to Steven Beaupre for adding the note from the vignette.

Comment: Can one have a general r statement in between? When I add a colnames function call in between the piped statements, I get an error    `df%<>%
  colnames(df)<-vector_columnnames%>%
  slice(-c(1:3))%>% 
  select(-c(Col1,Col50,Col51))`

Comment: I apologize for the follow up questions but since this thread probably will be useful to others, I'm putting it  here. What if I want to make a vector assignment that is not part of the functions in the dplyr/magittr packages like this `df%<>%
  vector_columnnames<-sprintf("Col%d",1:length(df))%>%
  set_colnames(vector_columnnames) %>%
  slice(-c(1:3))%>% # delete top 3 rows
  select(-c(Col1,Col50,Col51))` . The vector_columnnames statement is not executed. Any suggestions on how one would essentially set a temporary vector while piping?

Comment: if `df` is a data frame wouldn't `setNames()` work as well as `set_colnames()` ?

Comment: Yes. setNames also works. The set_colnames is an magrittr 'extract'.

Comment: It's worth noting that non-mutability is a really valuable programming strategy. Basically, never over-write an object. That way, you can re-run and debug any part of your code in any order. So maybe name the first one df.original and the second df.final, and avoid %<>% altogether.