# Using a loop to rename column names

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

I'm using `rename` from the `dplyr` library in R to rename column names. I tried to use a loop to achieve this, which runs without error. However, no column names are updated. The loop is:

```
for (i in 1:length(columns)) {
  newcol <- columns[i]
  oldcol <- names(census)[i]
  rename(census, newcol = oldcol) 
}
```

The 'columns' variable is a vector containing the new column names (of the same length as the old column names), and 'census' is the tibble containing the data with old column names. When just printing 'newcol' and 'oldcol' for each loop iteration, the names are correct - they just don't seem to then be renamed using the 'rename' line.

Comment: dplyr's functions don't rewrite their output. If you want to rename columns, you need to assign the data frame back to itself. There's also no need for a loop; `rename` can take any number of names at once, and can rename based on positions as well

Comment: Understood, thanks.

Comment: Some explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33335636/5325862

Answer (score 2):

Camille’s comment explains why your code doesn’t work.

To fix the code, you can drop the loop and directly assign the column names:

```
colnames(census) <- columns
```

When using `rename`, a bit more effort is required, since `rename` expects unevaluated column names, you need to tell it to evaluate the variables:

```
for (i in seq_along(columns)) {
  newcol <- columns[i]
  oldcol <- colnames(census)[i]
  census <- rename(census, !! newcol := !! oldcol) 
}
```

Or, once more dropping the unnecessary loop:

```
census <- rename(census, !!! setNames(colnames(census), columns))
```

Comment: That's great, thank you. The assignment requires the use of dplyr functions hence the use of `rename`. Thanks also for introducing me to `!!!` and `!!`!